# Calling functions with variables multiple times

Tags: python-3.x

I'm making a program for a school project and I'm having an issue.

I have defined a function called `DidThisWork` like so:

```
def DidThisWork():
    global DidThisWork
    DidThisWork = input('\n\nDid this solution work? - ').lower()
```

Throughout my code, I want to call this function multiple times, however, I'm not able to. Is there a way, to call it multiple times, and like reset the `DidThisWork` variable inside the function after I used it in `if` statements?

Comment: Why would you name a variable just like the function?

Answer (score 0):

You define a function `def DidThisWork():` then within that very function you overwrite the newly created `DidThisWork` variable (which points to the function) to the result of your `input(..)` call.

So at the first call to `DidThisWork()`, the `DidThisWork` variable no longer points to the *function*, rather to the string returned by `input(...)`.

If you rename either the function or the variable storing the string returned by `input()` it should work.

By the way, there are some naming conventions in Python you may want to look into https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id30. Typically you'd use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase` and not only start a `class` with an upper case letter

```
worked = None

def did_this_work():
    global worked
    worked = input('\n\nDid this solution work? - ').lower()

print(worked)
did_this_work()
print(worked)
did_this_work()
print(worked)
```